# Python Date() Function

Tags: python, date, tuples

I have what may be a dopey question about Python's date function.

Let's say I want to pass the script a date, July 2nd 2013. This code works fine:

```
from datetime import date
july_2nd = date(2013,7,2)
print july_2nd
```

Output:

```
2013-07-02
```

So now what if I want to pass the `date()` function a value stored in a variable, which I can set with a function, rather than hard coding 7/2/13, so I try this and get an error:

```
from datetime import date
july_2nd = (2013,7,2)
print date(july_2nd)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

You want to pass in the tuple as *separate* arguments, using the `*args` splat syntax:

```
date(*july_2nd)
```

By prefixing `july_2nd` with an asterisk, you are telling Python to call `date()` with all values from that variable as separate parameters.

See the [calls expression documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls) for details; there is a `**kwargs` form as well to expand mapping into keyword arguments.